# Check for host protected area and device configuration overlay

Tags: sata

I'd like to know whether any sectors on my solid state drive are inaccessible due to

- the host protected area ([HPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_protected_area))
- or the device configuration overlay ([DCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_configuration_overlay))

Is there a file in `/proc/` I can read or any tool I can use to find out about HPA and DCO?

I'm on Arch Linux 5.9.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## with [`hdparm`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/hdparm.8.html)

To find out about the host protected area, use `hdparm`'s `-N` option, for example

```
sudo hdparm -N /dev/sda
```

yields this on my machine:

```
/dev/sda:
max sectors   = 1953529856/1953529856, HPA is disabled
```

With `--dco-identify` we can find out about the device configuration overlay.

```
sudo hdparm --dco-identify /dev/sda
```

Example output:

```
/dev/sda:
DCO Checksum verified.
DCO Revision: 0x0002
The following features can be selectively disabled via DCO:
        Transfer modes:
                mdma0 mdma1 mdma2
                udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 udma6
        Real max sectors: 1953529856
        ATA command/feature sets:
                SMART error_log security 48_bit
                WRITE_UNC_EXT
        SATA command/feature sets:
                interface_power_management SSP
```

Let's focus on this line:

```
Real max sectors: 1953529856
```

Comparing this number with the "max sectors" line of `hdparm -N`, we can see that there is no sector hidden using DCO:

```
1953529856 - 1953529856 = 0
```